Sequential weak* compactness of bounded set in $(L^\infty(0,T; H))^*$
Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and consider the dual $L_T^* := (L^\infty(0,T; H))^*$ of the Bochner space $L^\infty(0,T; H)$. Let $\{ u_{\varepsilon} : \varepsilon > 0 \}$ denote a uniformly bounded set in $L_T^*$, i.e., there exists some $C > 0$ such that $\| u_\varepsilon\|_{L_T^*} := \sup_{\| v \|_{\infty} = 1} |u_\varepsilon(v)| \le C$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.
I am reading an article in which the authors seem to claim that this implies the existence of a subsequence $(u_{\varepsilon_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converging weakly-star in $L_T^*$ (where the indices $(\varepsilon_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are strictly decreasing and converge to zero). The argument is as follows (see page 362):
Consider the isometric linear embedding $\Gamma \colon C([0,T]; H) \to L^\infty(0,T; H)$ which sends every $v \in C([0,T];H)$ to its a.e. equivalence class in $L^\infty(0,T; H)$. Then its adjoint $\Gamma^* \colon L_T^* \to (C([0,T]; H))^*$ is bounded, so that $\{ \Gamma^* u_{\varepsilon} : \varepsilon > 0 \}$ is a bounded set in $(C([0,T];H))^*$. Since $C([0,T];H)$ is separable, the Banach–Alaoglu theorem yields the sequential weak-star compactness of $\{ \Gamma^* u_{\varepsilon} : \varepsilon > 0 \}$. And then, "since $\Gamma$ is an endomorphism from $C([0,T]; H)$ into $L^\infty(0,T; H)$, this implies that $\{ u_{\varepsilon} : \varepsilon > 0 \}$ is weak-star sequentially compact in $L_T^*$ as claimed".
I don't understand how the authors reach their conclusion in the final step. I suspect that by endomorphism they mean continuous embedding, but I don't see how this would help. If I consider the weak-star convergent subsequence $(\Gamma^* u_{\varepsilon_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with limit $y \in (C([0,T];H))^*$, then we have $\Gamma^* u_{\varepsilon_n}(v) \to y(v)$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $v \in C([0,T];H)$. I can relate this back to $u_{\varepsilon_n}$ via the definition of the adjoint, i.e., $u_{\varepsilon_n}(\Gamma v) \to y(v)$, but this only tells us something about the convergence of $u_{\varepsilon_n}(\,\cdot\,)$ against continuous functions.
Moreover, the fact that the closed unit ball of $(\ell^\infty(\mathbb N))^*$ is not sequentially weak-star compact suggests to me that this claim may be false. But I could be missing something.

Is the sequence of indices $(\varepsilon_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ supposed to be strictly decreasing and convergent to $0$?

This would be true, if $\Gamma^$ would be invertible (i.e., $(\Gamma^)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded). However $\Gamma^*$ is not injective, so ...

@P.P.Tuong In practice, yes. The context of the problem is that we are approximating an equation for each $\varepsilon > 0$ and trying to extract a subsequence as $\varepsilon \to 0$ which should converge to a solution of the original equation.

@user486506 I see. It's interesting to know that while finding a weak-$$ convergent subsequence isn't always possible, you can take the weak-$$ limit of $\varepsilon\mapsto u_\varepsilon$ along an ultrafilter on $(0,\infty)$ containing all the sets of the form $(0,\varepsilon)$ with $\varepsilon>0$, and this is very likely to give you a solution of your equation.

Could you maybe give a reference to the article? Just in case it helps other users determine a way to modify the argument, depending on what is needed of the sequence or subsequence for example. I don't know if I can help beyond what I proposed. Have a nice day/night!

@BrunoB: Sure, done!

@P.P.Tuong: In fact, as you can see in the article, the authors start by noting that one can apply the Alaoglu theorem directly to $L_T^*$ itself to get the result for "generalized sequences" (i.e., nets or filters) as you suggest, and the argument above is presented as a trick to use regular sequences anyway. But that does not seem to work, so maybe indeed one has to use filters.

We can actually just tweak the construction from the post you linked to obtain the same result for $L^\infty$, that is:

The unit ball of the dual of $L^\infty$ is not weak-star sequentially compact.

Note that this won't prevent smaller subsets from being weak-$*$ sequentially compact, however this should mean that the argument from the authors of the article you mention might need to be refined or be made clearer. I'm not an expert on the matter though.
Proof: I'll go for the case $H = \mathbb{C}$ but it should be clear how to adapt the construction otherwise.
Consider the sequence $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ defined by $u_n(f) := \Lambda_n(f \cdot \chi_{I_n})$ where $I_n$ is the interval $\left(\frac{T}{n+1}, \frac{T}{n}\right)$, $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of a set $A$, and $\Lambda_n$ is the integration functional on $I_n$: $$\Lambda_n(g) := \frac{1}{m(I_n)}\int_{I_n} g(t)\mathrm{d}t$$ which is evidently continuous on $L^\infty(I_n)$ ($\Lambda_n$ is well-defined because bounded measurable functions are integrable on the set $I_n$ of finite measure).
Now, for any subsequence $(u_{\varphi(k)})_k$ of $(u_n)_n$, consider the (equivalence class of) the below function $$f_\varphi : x \mapsto \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } x \notin I_{\varphi(k)} \text{ for all $k$}\\ (-1)^k \text{ if } x \in I_{\varphi(k)}\end{cases}$$
It is clear that $f$ is $L^\infty$, and that:
$$u_{\varphi(k)}(f_\varphi) = (-1)^k$$
which does not converge as $k$ tends to $\infty$.
This construction prevents any subsequence of $(u_n)_n$ from weak-$*$ converging, and all the $u_n$s are elements of the closed unit ball of the dual of $L^\infty([0, T])$ since:
$$|u_n(f)| \leq \|\Lambda_n\| \|f \cdot \chi_{I_n}\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty$$ thus the latter cannot be weak-$*$ sequentially compact.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
As you can see, the only thing that changes between $\ell^\infty$ and $L^\infty$ is finding another way to "take the $n$-th coordinate", so it was simple to tweak. Feel free to let me know if I made a mistake though.
